# Do NPCs forget their hostility towards you if they initially were neutral?

Tags: this-war-of-mine

I visited a place where they caught me stealing, and one of the NPCs ran after me with a gun, attempting to shoot me. I got away. Now this is my problem.

If I revisit, will they still be mad at me? and is this character dependend?

Say, I stole stuff with Pavle but returned with Katia. Would that be any different?

Comment: I can confirm that they will still be mad at the same character. At least the next night. Made me want to quit the game because I couldn't access the market anymore after accidently stabbing someone...

Comment: Thats a nice pointer, thanks. One thing I dislike about the game is that "exploring" the mechanics has such big consequences due to the lack of save functionality. But, on the other hand, it facilitates a great deal of seriousness which is quite essential for the game.

Comment: News: Two day after initial visit, where we lost Katia, we used Bruno to Scavenge the Brothel. They were not hostile towards him.

Comment: So I guess that means hostility only remains for the character that caused it. That's good to know, I would've been able to visit the market with another character.

Comment: Most likely. But days between might also be a factor that plays in. One should keep that in mind. :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they will be hostile againts the chartcher that made them hostile.
But the madness only goes to him, meanning, If you try and go with a different person, They'll go back to netural on you.
They won't cause any harm to Katia.